# Database Doesn't Contain Current Data After Restoring Last Full Backup from Production

Tags: sql-server, backup

I restored my last full backup from production database to reporting database server, but last restored database on my reporting server doesn't contain current tables, procedures, functions etc. What can cause this situation? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue when you back up to the same file over and over again. Without `WITH INIT`, the new backup gets *appended* to the file, it doesn't overwrite it. So in this example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE model TO DISK = 'c:\temp\model.bak' WITH COMPRESSION;
GO
USE model;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.newtable(id int);
GO
BACKUP DATABASE model TO DISK = 'c:\temp\model.bak' WITH COMPRESSION;
```

We can see from `RESTORE HEADERONLY` that there are two backups:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\temp\model.bak';
```

Partial results:

```
Position        BackupFinishDate
-------------   -----------------------
1               2019-09-03 14:01:08.000
2               2019-09-03 14:01:11.000
```

Guess which one has `dbo.newtable`? Guess which one is used as the default when you just say `RESTORE ... FROM DISK ...;`?

If you're going to continue using this method to back up your databases, you'll need to determine the `Position` to pass to `RESTORE ... WITH FILE = <position>` so that you get the latest backup. A better practice IMHO is to always use `BACKUP ... WITH INIT` and append timestamps to the file name. This makes it easier both to ensure you're using the latest backup and also to remove older backups.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a database restoration, all your current data as well as objects - tables, views, functions, procedure anything which is inside database is lost and you get all the objects of the database whose(from) full back up was restored.

In case, you were not aware of this - check if you had any scheduled job running on reporting server which was taking full backup and that backup is clean. if the backup is clean, you can restore on another database or on this database based on your requirement.

Ideally you should have taken full backup of your reporting database before restoring your production database over this server.

Hope above helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazing answer. Best regards @Learning_DBAdmin